# Constantness of the field renormalisation constant (according to Sidney Coleman)

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I encountered the following passage in *Quantum Field Theory: Lectures of Sidney Coleman*, page 280:

> Since Lorentz transformations don't change $\phi'(0)$, or change any
>   one-meson state to any other one-meson state, the coefficient $\langle k\rvert\phi'(0)\lvert 0\rangle$ of $e^{ik\cdot x}$ must be Lorentz
>   invariant, and so can depend only on $k^2$. Then $k^2=\mu^2$, and
>   $\langle k\rvert\phi'(0)\lvert 0\rangle$ is a constant.

Then the author goes on defining the field renormalisation constant $Z_3$ from this quantity.

My problem is, I thought that one-meson states $\lvert k\rangle$ were *not* invariant, since they should transform to $\lvert \Lambda k\rangle$, $\Lambda$ being the Lorentz transform.
The other quantity, $\phi'(0)$, is surely constant since $\phi$ is a scalar field and $\Lambda 0=0$.
I checked in the previous chapters on scalar fields, and indeed I found this transformation law.
What am I missing here? Is that quantity really Lorentz-invariant, and if so, how can it be explained?

Comment: Write |k⟩ as U(Λ)|0⟩, where Lambda is the Lorentz transformation that takes k to (μ,0,0,0). Make the same U act on the vacuum (it is invariant under Lorentz transformations). Then you get something like $U^{\dagger}\phi(0)U$ which will again give you back $\phi(0)$. Since μ is a constant, the field strength renormalization will also be a constant.

Comment: Is $\lvert 0 \rangle$ in your first equation the vacuum state?

Comment: No it's not, thats state has zero three momentum.

Comment: So... by your first comment, I should get (I'll call $\lvert\emptyset\rangle$ the vacuum state) that $\langle k\rvert\phi'(0)\lvert\emptyset\rangle=\langle 0\rvert U(\Lambda)^{-1}\phi'(0)\lvert\emptyset\rangle$... then since $U(\Lambda)^{-1}\phi'(0)U(\Lambda)=\phi'(0)$ I obtain $U(\Lambda)^{-1}\phi'(0)=\phi'(0)U(\Lambda)^{-1}$, and then $\phi'(0)U(\Lambda)^{-1}\lvert\emptyset\rangle=\phi'(0)\lvert\emptyset\rangle$ following from the invariance of the vacuum state. Is this what you mean? (Even then, this is not the quantity I started from...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this. Since $\phi'$ is a scalar field we have
\begin{equation}
U(\Lambda)\phi'(x)U(\Lambda)^{-1}=\phi'(\Lambda^{-1}x),
\end{equation}
for any element $\Lambda$ of the Lorentz group, therefore
\begin{equation}
\langle k\rvert\phi'(0)\lvert 0\rangle=
\langle k\rvert U(\Lambda)^{-1}\phi'(0)U(\Lambda)\lvert 0\rangle=
\langle \Lambda k\rvert\phi'(0)\lvert 0\rangle
\end{equation}
which means that $\langle k\rvert\phi'(0)\lvert 0\rangle$ is invariant with respect to Lorentz transformations of $k$.
This implies that the function

1. doesn't depend on $k$, or
2. is a function of $k^2$ only, since this is the only invariant quantity we can build from $k$.

Since every particle associated to the field $\phi'$ has the same mass $\mu$, and $k^2=\mu^2$, the function $\langle k\rvert\phi'(0)\lvert 0\rangle$ actually doesn't depend on $k$ in any of the two cases.